# Размер scrollView по вертикали

Tags: android, eclipse, прокрутка

Здравствуйте,подскажите пожалуйста свойство scrollView которое показывает общий(не только видимый но и тот который за пределами экрана) вертикальный размер scrollView(у меня с текстом),желательно в пикселях. То есть мне нужен размер,который был бы если бы планшет был такого размера что бы в него помещался весь текст. Смысл в том что эта длина будет разная при разных размерах букв.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Передаём гуглу строку

> [scrollview get content height](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=scrollview%20get%20content%20height)

2) Получаем [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4989894/3212712):

```
int totalHeight = scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
```

3) Если запускаем это в onCreate() активити (т.е. до onResume()), то получим "0", т.к. в этот момент ещё не измерены элементы. Засим пользуем код из п.2 в onResume();

4) Если совсем надо в onCreate(), то см сюда: [ссылка на хак](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7735122/3212712)

Comment: Спасибо,то что надо!!!

Comment: @Алексей., помимо "спасибо" тут приветствуется голос "за" правильный ответ и галочка "принять". =)